# JQuery Mobile Performance Monitoring

Tags: performance, jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile app. I would really like to tweak the performance of the application. In order to help me, I'm looking for tools that may help with this. Ultimately, I would like to be able to monitor memory usage, responsiveness, and cpu usage. However, I can't seem to find any tools that help accomplish these goals. Does anyone know of any tools to help with this? If so, what are they?

Thank you